# My pals keep getting depressed working the mines and are lazy. How do I make them stop complaining and keep working?

Tags: palworld

I put all my pals to work and yet the only ones that get depressed seems to be the ones that work at the mine. Everyone else seems relatively fine.

Throwing them in the hot tub helps temporarily regaining their sanity, but they'll fall back to their old ways not too long.

How can I reduce the chances they get depressed?

In a second base, I found a spot with many ore deposits and wanted to set up camp there. Have four Tombats with lv2 mining to tackle the mining (~8-9 ore deposits), and the rest are mostly pals with transport to take the mined ore to storage. The Tombats are still losing san, more than it is replenishing compared to all the other pals.

For reference, here's some screenshots of my bases:

base 1
[image: starter base]

base 2
[image: mining base]

Comment: There are pills for that.

Comment: Darn, thought this title would be perfect for an "out of context network question title" but not as much traffic as we used to have. ‎

Comment: I have found the trouble is that the Mine (and Logging Site) have continuous work, whereas the other roles are much more "to order". I might try having more Mining Pals than Mining slots (e.g. 3 miners, 1 mining site) so that at any given hour, one of them can be in the hot tub or whatever.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I had similar thoughts. The logging one isn't as bad, it can only hold two pals if I'm not mistaken and while their san drops, they never seem to get to the depressed state. Mining on the other hand holds three and they're still getting depressed. Mining ore directly has no limit as far as I can see. Maybe mining reduces san more than chopping wood does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pal AI can be glitchy at times, and while you're away from the base, the game simulates them as if you were there.

And sometimes, Pals can get stuck or glitch out of the world.

When it does glitch, your Pal will just stand there starving to death, getting sprained or depressed, etc. instead of pathing to food or rest.

You could try:

- Spreading things out
- Avoiding putting things under low roofs; to be safe, the roof should be two stories high. This isn't an issue for the early/low (1-20) level pals, but the latter ones are 1.5-2 stories tall.
- Have your base on flat land
- Avoid multi-level bases; AI pathing can glitch out
- Try making paths at least two tiles wide
- Adding more bath tubs, feeding better food and making better beds
- Make sure your Pals can path to bed, hot tubs and food
- Adding more Pals to do mining/chopping so that there is less work per Pal

As always, you should try to follow the game's specifications:

- All Pals **NEED** a bed
- Make sure Pals can access a feed station and it is stocked

Another thing you could check for are:

- Placing down a *Monitoring Stand* and making sure that it is set to the lowest setting.

**tl;dr: Wait for patch or try to plan around the jank.**

[image: A working mining base]

This mining base has been working for me without a single injury for at least half a day realtime.
This same setup has been working for me even when all the beds are basic.

It is somewhat balanced, and the amount of miners isn't enough to miner it out with downtime. As such, the mining Pals do not get any downtime other than night time rest and food (aka. a constant stream of Cooked Berries), yet it can continue without much maintainance.

Even if I don't attend it for a whole day, at most there would be only 3 or 4 injuries that need treating with medicine.

There's a Tombat (previously had 2) in this base and it is usually the Digturtles getting depressed by getting trapped in the hill until I fixed the base design. I've never had a Tombat go depressed.

Comment: While I think this is generally useful information, it doesn't really address the question. Pals that do mining _will_ get depressed more frequently than others (if at all). How do I manage them?

Comment: Can you maybe include a screenshot of your base? @JeffMercado

Comment: I'll grab screenshots of my bases as the currently stand when I get the chance. The first base has changed slightly since I asked this and feed changed a bit so while not as frequent as before, still gets depressed over time. Might just be a matter of not being able to replenish san as much as they are fed.

Comment: Pals definitely glitches out at spots and eventually dies or gets seriously injured. Where I set up my first base is definitely not ideal and I plan to move it to a more suitable place soon. Transferring stuff out will be a pain tho.

Comment: Added screenshots of my bases currently. Base 2 is the weirdest, was initially using Vanwyrms since they had fire and transport but they kept killing themselves when they wandered around and got stuck in the trees by the entrance. I could probably prevent that by placing floors there so the trees would stop spawning.

Comment: @JeffMercado Try moving the back row of beds in both bases away from the cliff/ruins, since when they wake up, they may end up in the cliff (though even doing that I *still* have Pals randomly disappearing). Also your second base could do with another hot tub or two...

Answer (score 4):

Are you paying attention to the passives of your Pals? There are passives that drain SAN and Food quicker; you should be able to check each of the Pals at your base by hovering over them and pressing F. Ideally you'll want ones like Positive Thinker or Workaholic, which reduce the rate at which SAN depletes.

Do your mining Pals have multiple uses? I'm not sure what they're called, they're the ability to harvest, Plant, Mine, Lumber, Handicraft, etc. Cattiva for example will Mine, but it also will try to Harvest and Transport, meaning it has more opportunities to continue working instead of resting.

Comment: I thought about the "multiple use" thing and with that in mind started a second base built for mining ore at a spot where there were many ore deposits. It needed pals with lv2 mining which I had Tombats for and they did not have the transport skill. Got multiple to try to distribute the "depression" to try to reduce the chances and have many other with transport to move the ores to storage. The miners san dropped the most still. I think it might be inherent in mining to drop san the most at this point in the game.

Comment: @JeffMercado It's entirely possible; the game's only been out for a week so we can't know all the intricacies of the Pals yet. I've also heard that cooked food restores SAN, as opposed to just raw berries, so perhaps getting a dedicated cook Pal can help keep everyone healthier.

Comment: Up until my last session, I hade been feeding my pals mostly baked berries (or whatever it was called). According to stats if we're reading it right, should have recovered 1 san. Moved on to berry toast now that I have wheat. That should regain more san and lately I haven't been seeing it as much as I used to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like ultimately, the issue was that I wasn't feeding them food that restores enough SAN as working the mines depletes it. Leading to them losing SAN to the point they get depressed. So get off raw or cooked berries as soon as you can if you are doing a lot of mining.

Having mining labor camps would not be really sustainable unless you either:

- Feed them food that restores more SAN than they lose it
- Swap in pals with with full SAN when the miners get depressed
- Make sure to regularly pull them off the mine and put them in the hot tubs (or do other SAN restoring activities)

I really don't want to have to micromanage this where I have to constantly swap my pals in/out or keep pulling them out to throw in the hot tub. Fortunately I'm at a level where I can feed them slightly better food, enough to keep them out of depression.